# Multiple proc calls in Entity Framework causing error - New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

First time we are seeing this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

I think it might be because I am using one `DbContext` and multiple threads inside of it. Trying to think of a solution, the code looks something like this:

```
using (var db = new DbContext)
{
    db.sp_updateTable1(params);
    db.sp_updateTable2(params);
    db.sp_updateTable2(params);   
    // ...
}
```

Each procedure call is a function import in Entity Framework, so calls this function:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_updateTable1", params);
```

Do I need to wrap each procedure call inside of its own using statement - so I'll end up having 3 using statements above, or is there an easier way to fix this (less messy code)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I think it might be because I am using one DbContext and multiple threads inside of it.

That's not supported.

"DbContext is not thread-safe. Do not share contexts between threads. Make sure to await all async calls before continuing to use the context instance."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

Comment: For some reason the code has been working fine like that for a while so I wasn't aware of this. What would you suggest as a solution?